# Rails: Fail to get updated assets precompile file in production server. No any update on fingerprint of assets file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, assets, production, precompile

In my rails server, while i deploy my code from local machine(Mac PC) to production machine(Linux Ubuntu) through `capistrano` with the command, `cap production deploy`, everything is alright except for the asset file update.

I found there's no any update of my asset files, js and css, in many times. Sometimes it updated and sometimes if failed. The probability of fail is about 80%.
If it passed, i could get the pass log as below, which show the new js file with fingerprint.

```
INFO [1fccb6d2] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxx
DEBUG [1fccb6d2] Command: cd /home/deploy/myeyehouse/releases/20160528162211 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [1fccb6d2]     [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
DEBUG [1fccb6d2]     I, [2016-05-29T00:23:08.129214 #14695]  INFO -- : Writing */home/deploy/myeyehouse/releases/20160128162211/public/assets/application-cdfb70e59238ab6d9142e0baba154b101ea4aef9b0a0cab3ea528469faed3704.js*
INFO [1fccb6d2] Finished in 8.168 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

And for the failed log as below, which doesn't show up any js file.

```
INFO [b8b2d3fc] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as deploy@xx.xx.xxx.xxx
DEBUG [b8b2d3fc] Command: cd /home/deploy/myeyehouse/releases/20160622164438 && ( RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
DEBUG [b8b2d3fc]     [DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
INFO [b8b2d3fc] Finished in 3.724 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
```

When it failed, my new js files would ,of course, not update to my production server. And then the users who visit my server would get serious error.
I tried to execute the command on my production server, `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`, it still not worked. No any new js file produced.

And the weird point is that when i execute this command in my local machine, it worked!!
Thus, my current workaround solution is execute precompile command in my local machine and push this file to my production to replace the older one. 
But this would lead to another issue, the file name with the fingerprint of precompile file would not change, thus some users would still get error due to the cache from browser until they refresh the page. 
I thought this would not a good solution to handle this issue. Do anyone encounter this issue?

My server language is RoR(Ruby on Rails)

On local environment `rails version 4.2.2`, `ruby version 2.1.2p95`

On production environment `rails version 4.2.4`, `ruby version 2.2.2p95`

The gems i used: `capistrano-rails`, `capistrano-passenger`, `carrierwave`, `rmagick`, `mysql2`, `deivise`...